# JSON — Parse Error with new Date(...)

Tags: javascript, json

Why is this JSON giving me parse errors? I could swear I've done this a hundred times before without issue.

```
[[0,0,0,new Date(1364068990245)],[0,0,0,new Date(1364068940075)]]
```

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: _"I've done this a hundred times before"_ - oh no you haven't...

Comment: I presumed that any valid JS array or object was "JSON."

Comment: @MatthewH JSON's syntax is based on JavaScript's literals syntax, thus the name. But, it uses a strict subset, making it more restrictive. http://json.org/

Comment: Far from all code valid in Javascript is allowed in JSON. An array literal in Javascript can for example contain code that would execute when you parse it: `[(function(){alert('Oh noes!');return 0;}())]`. Consider what evil things you could do with that...

Comment: I noticed that the JSON.NET NuGet library's JavaScriptDateTimeConverter seems to serialize DateTime values in this way, but it doesn't follow its typical pattern of encoding strongly-typed objects, which is to include a "type$" member in the object.  I had to re-create the class as an AS3DateTimeConverter that serializes it using the standard typed object notation as `{"type$":"System.DateTime","epoch":123456,"ticks":{"type$":"System.Int64","value":"0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"}}` to perform the translation, which includes the epoch offset and the long ticks value in case full precision is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's literal JavaScript, as in this:

```
var myArray = [[0,0,0.......]];
```

Then it should be fine, your error must be coming from somewhere else.

If it's a string that you're treating as JSON, as in this:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse("[[0,0,0.........]]");
```

Then you can't have `new Date` (or indeed any function call) and it should be just a number that you then parse into a date.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `new` operator isn't part of JSON. Your example is a valid fragment of a JavaScript file, but it correctly results in an error when parsed as JSON. Dates should be serialized as strings (ideally, as ISO-8601 strings that will be accepted by the `Date` constructor, but I suppose numbers are tolerable as well).

Comment: FYI, this might be parsed by the JSON.NET library, as its JavaScriptDateTimeConverter, when added to the serializer's settings, will output dates using the new operator like this, although it's not standard JSON: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net

Answer (score 1):

That's not JSON, there are no dates in the JSON format.

Ref: http://www.json.org/

Some JSON parsers have extended the standard with this way of representing a date:

```
"[[0,0,0,/Date(1364068990245)/],[0,0,0,/Date(1364068940075)/]]"
```

If the parser that you use doesn't support that, you have to transmit them as a different data type, for example numbers, and then convert them to dates after parsing the JSON:

```
"[[0,0,0,1364068990245],[0,0,0,1364068940075]]"
```

Comment: The "new Date(0)" format may be parsed by the JSON.NET library, as its JavaScriptDateTimeConverter, when added to the serializer's settings, will output dates using the new operator like this, although it's not standard JSON: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net